# Proxy rewriting to new domain?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

My question is regarding `RewriteMap` on apache2: I want to apply a rewrite condition, so that all request on my proxy are proxied to an completely new domain.

Eg `localhost/test` or any other url should just go to `www.mydomain.com`:

```
RewriteRule / http://www.mydomain.com [P]
```

Works fine. If I access localhost, I still see "localhost" in my browser address line, but mydomain.com is presented. BUT if I now click on any link on this mydomain site, I will get a "Not Found" response.

The sourecode of mydomain contains eg this link:

```
<a href="/lab/sale.php">Link</a>
```

If I access the site in a normal way, this would result in: `www.mydomain.com/lab/sale.php`, and works fine.

If I access the site through my proxy and the rewriteRule takes place, I would after the link click be directed to: `localhost/lab/sale.php`, which does not exist of course.

Question: how can I a user that accesses the site through my proxy browse on the whole site as if he would really access this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RewriteRule` directive isn't like a `ProxyPass` or `Redirect` where they essentially link 2 nodes together and everything following it also gets proxied. The rule that you have **only** proxies the request URI `/`, not `/lab/` or `/etc.php` or anything else. You need to create a match and pass that along as a backreference:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [P]
```

Or you can use the %{REQUEST_URI} variable:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Comment: I do not want to append the requested path URI to my redirection! I just want to redirect to a new location. On that new location, if I click a link on that page, then this link is evaluated to localhost/link/path instead of just working like the normal page.

Comment: @membersound Your original rule does that. It will only proxy `/`, not `/lab/sale.php`. So either the link you clicked contained a `http://www.mydomain.com/` in front (which there is nothing the rewrite engine can do about) or the `/lab/sale.php` link doesn't exist on localhost.

Comment: Hm I still don't get it. I tried this: `RewriteRule /start/?(.*) http://www.google.com [P]`
`RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.google.com/$1 [P]` which should present the google page if I access `localhost/start/`. Which is the case, but also a full redirect takes place and changes the browser url. This is what I'd like to prevent. The url in browser should stay localhost/start. But all links should work afterwards...

Comment: @membersound That's got nothing to do with the rules, That's because google is redirecting you once you've gotten there.

Comment: Ok makes it clear for general understanding. Anyhow for my specific case I still cannot get it working. I have a hosts file. If I go to localhost/start/key, the key is looked up in hosts and dns is returned. So the website of this is presented, while localhost/start/key is still displayed. Each link contained in this website should then be usable just as I would access it directly. I tried:

`RewriteRule /start/?(.*)$ http://${myhosts:$1}/ [P]`
`RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://${myhosts:$1}/$1 [P]`. But that still won't work.

Comment: It would basically work if I omit the ending slash for the first statement, like `RewriteRule /start/?(.*)$ http://${myhosts:$1}` BUT then the browser url will change! What do I have to change on this for the browser url to remain?

Comment: @membersound It's probably the remote server redirecting because of `DirectorySlash`, there's nothing you can do about it on the proxying end. If the mydomain.com server wants to redirect, your browser gets redirected.

Comment: @membersound It isn't possible with a `RewriteRule`, but if you use `ProxyPass`, together with `ProxyPassReverse`, it will rewrite the 301/302 redirects as they come through, and that should prevent this problem.

Comment: it should not be the remote server. i own it and am running just a zest servlet with some links on it. how could i else handle my task. i need rewritemap to look up hosts l.ater